# Run a javascript before a user browses to a new page or closes browser

Tags: javascript

I collect data about what a user does on a page. I want the data collection to stop when the visitor leaves the page. I am able to collect data if the visitor navigates to a new page with out a problem with the below script. However, if the visitor closes the tab or browser window the data is lost. How can I preserve the functionality of sending it to the database no matter how the visitor leaves the page?

```
theData = '';
window.onbeforeunload = pageUnload; 

function pageUnload(){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.thesite.com/collector.php?data="+theData+"",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: the only way to guarantee that code will work is to make it synchronous - but that's deprecated so who knows how long it will work. chrome/firefox have sendBeacon - but IE does not, so no joy there

Comment: Sending an Ajax request when browser closes in modern browsers is going to be a failure. They kill off any active/pending http requests.

Comment: @JaromandaX - The synchronous change is actually a good idea to temporarily solve the issue. I didn't even think of that. Just tested it and it works good enough. I'll look into sendBecon. Maybe Edge will support it.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=beacon - no love for sendBeacon

Comment: Is it possible to do it in server side?
I mean, is it possible to do the job when session time out?

Comment: If you want to collect the data when a user closes the tab, then obviously you are not using it to change the user experience in real time.  You could use local storage in your `onbeforeunload` function, and then upload the data next time the user visits (by checking for anything in local storage and deleting it once successfully submitted).